# Rails: Show each data with index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's a simple question.

For example, I have 3 data

```
number  name  country
1       Jack  US
2       Coda  UK
3       Fredy TW
```

How do I display this number in `rails` dynamically.

here is part of code

```
<% @stay_times.each do |s| %>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <%#= I don't know what to put here %>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <%= s.name %>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <%= s.nationality %>
                </td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where is the data stored? How do you fetch it?

Comment: I didn't set number field, so I want it display automatically. s.id will display the number of id, so it may not start by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use [each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) method:

```
<% @stay_times.each_with_index do |s, index| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= index + 1 %> <!-- index starts with zero -->
    </td>
   <td>
     <%= s.name %>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= s.nationality %>
   </td>
<% end %>
```

> **each_with_index(*args) public**
>
> Calls block with two arguments, the item and its index, for each item
>   in enum. Given arguments are passed through to #each().
>
> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

```
hash = Hash.new
%w(cat dog wombat).each_with_index {|item, index|
  hash[item] = index
}
hash   #=> {"cat"=>0, "dog"=>1, "wombat"=>2}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. BTW, Does any method I can use like `StayTime.size` or `StayTime.count` to get number quickly and achieve what I want?

Comment: @CodaChang `@stay_times.count` ?

Comment: Never mind, actually I don't know what I am talking about haha.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to use `<%= s.number %>` for the line where you have a comment. It depends on what the `number` field in the data table is called in your `@stay_times` variable. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that, I don't have the `number` column. I want it to be create automatically.